# KERN-EXEC 3 when navigating within a text box (Symbian OS Browser Control)

Tags: webkit, webbrowser-control, symbian, s60, s60-3rd-edition

I've had nothing but grief using Symbian's browser control on S60 3rd edition FP1. We currently display pages and many things are working smoothly. However, when inputting text into an HTML text field, the user will get a KERN-EXEC 3 if they move left at the beginning of the text input area (which should "wrap" it to the end) or if they move right at the end  of the text input area (which should "wrap" it to the beginning).

I can't seem to trap the input in `OfferKeyEventL`. I get the key event, I return `EKeyWasConsumed` and the cursor still moves.

```
TKeyResponse CMyAppContainer::OfferKeyEventL(const TKeyEvent& aKeyEvent, TEventCode aType)
{
  if (iBrCtlInterface) // My browser control
  {
    TBrCtlDefs::TBrCtlElementType type = iBrCtlInterface->FocusedElementType();

    if (type == TBrCtlDefs::EElementActivatedInputBox || type == TBrCtlDefs::EElementInputBox)
    {
      if (aKeyEvent.iScanCode == EStdKeyLeftArrow || aKeyEvent.iScanCode == EStdKeyRightArrow)
      {
         return EKeyWasConsumed;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would be okay with completely disabling arrow key navigation but can't seem to do this.

Any ideas? Am I going about this the wrong way? Has anyone here even worked with the Browser Control library (browserengine.lib) on S60 3.1?

**Update**: Interestingly, if I switch to use Cursor Navigation, it works fine. For now, this is a workaround. I'm still curious to know if there are ways to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, if I switch to use Cursor Navigation, it works fine. For now, this is a workaround. I'm still curious to know if there are ways to resolve this. For now, I'm calling this the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would get quicker answer probably in http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/.

Comment: I've created a thread there as well -- it's a pity it's so hard to get info on Symbian. At least we don't intend to use it much longer -- it's looking like we're migrating to iPhone and Android support only.

Comment: Good luck with iPhone :)
Usually Nokia forum gives quite good feedback. Unless you are trying to do something really original.

Does it crash also in other phone models and op. systems (3.0, 3.2, 5.0)? It's not uncommon to have lots of bugs in Symbian